# Get Subject from header

Tags: c#, gmail-api

```
Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest header = new UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest(service, userId, messageId);

header.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Metadata;

header.MetadataHeaders = "Subject";
```

That is what I have so far and all I am looking to do is return the subject line. I have been messing with it for awhile and think that is fine but cannot find anything on the next step to just get it.

Any help is appreciated.

OK just in case someone else needs the help, the completed code worked out like this:

```
          Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest header = new UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest(service, userId, messageId);
      header.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Metadata;
      header.MetadataHeaders = new[] {"Subject", "From", "Date"};

      Message Response = header.Execute();
      var reqFrom = Response.Payload.Headers.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Name == "From");
      var reqDate = Response.Payload.Headers.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Date");
      var reqSubject = Response.Payload.Headers.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Subject");
      var reqReturn = Response.Payload.Headers.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Return-Path");

      string from = reqFrom.Value; 
      string date = reqDate.Value;
      string subject = reqSubject.Value;
      string returnEmail = reqReturn.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're getting very close. The general step to take next, is to print out the payload from the service request. For this to work, your request via [Users.messages.Get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) is successful, this method will returns a [Users.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) resource in the response body. Here is how I did in Python:

## Calling the Users.Messages.Get

```
message = service.users().messages().get(userId=userId, id=emailID, format='metadata').execute()
```

## Print out the "Subject" line

```
print (message['payload']['headers'][#]['value'])
```

Also, I suggest using the [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#try-it) below to call this method on live data and see the response. Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to not print (I am not familiar with Python so if I am understanding you incorrectly I apologize) but to use it as a variable for SQL input

Comment: @Piizzadude You could just save the `message['payload']['headers'][#]['value']` in a variable and use it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/robulouski/7441883

This will surely help you. The given code is in python but i think u will get some basic knowledge to go ahead. or else u can convert it if u want.

This code will give all the subjects of the mails as an output inside any folder you mention.